# Drop rows with specific values in all columns Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I got a dataframe and I want to drop all the rows that contain a value >= 100 in all the columns (in the whole dataframe), not in just one specific column.
I tried :
df = df[(df < 100).any()]
df.drop(df[(df <= 100)].index, inplace=True)

But nothing work...
Could you please help ?

Comment: Do you want any row where *any* value is >= 100 to be dropped, or do you want any where where *every* value is >= 100 to be dropped? It's not 100% clear in your question.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Once you have the Boolean mask (`df >= 100` or `df.ge(100)`) you can select the rows where all values are `True` with `all(axis=1)`, then reverse the resulting mask with `~` to select the desired rows from the original df.

```py
df = df[~df.ge(100).all(axis=1)]
```